# Login screen will not show list of users

Tags: macos, upgrade, login, big-sur, login-screen

After I upgraded from Catalina to Big Sur 11.2 on a 2019 iMac, the login screen no longer displays my username but instead the Username and Password prompts.

I have `List of users` selected in **Users & Group** and I *do not* have FileVault enabled.

[image]

[image]

How do I get macOS to display my username again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried deliberately selecting the `Name and password` option in System Preferences > Users & Groups, rebooting, then re-selecting the `List of users` option, and then rebooting again?

In my experience, some munged-up preferences files (.plists) can be 'fixed' in this manner.

Comment: The “make it wrong, reboot to clear system state, then make it correct right after reboot” will demonstrate preference file and database corruption very effectively.  +1

Comment: When this doesn't work, there's always the 'nuke the .plist file' method, but that can be problematical with SIP enabled.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This solved the issue for me.