# Accessibility > Menu Bar sizing does not seem to work at all?

Tags: menu-bar, bug, big-sur, accessibility, 4k

I've recently acquired a 4K 32" display and decided I'll stick with 4k without scaling (IMO scaling is virtually useless for 4k, you can barely use the MacOS it's that sluggish, really disappointing TBH :().

Anyway one of the top priorities for me is having a bigger menu bar as the default one @ 4k is really tiny. Luckily there's an option of having large menu bar under System Preferences > Accessibility > Display, but once I set it to "Large" it says it requires to log me out, then logs me out and once I'm back... nothing changes. Restarting and changing this option again does nothing either.

Any ideas what's wrong? Does it work for you? I'm on Big Sur 11.1.

[image: 4k]

Comment: You might review this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411898/login-screen-will-not-show-list-of-users/412091#comment576014_412091 IconDaemon's answer and bmike's comment suggest a way to handle this sort of (presumed) .plist corruption.

Comment: I've been changing these options & restarting like crazy, it does not seem to help at all :( This is a fairly new Mac Mini so I'd be really surprised .plist files are already broken.

Comment: Was worth a try. As a test, I set each Menu bar text size state, then took a screenshot so I could open both at once to compare sizes. Large is larger, but not very much larger...they're distinct but pretty hard to tell apart. This is macOS 11.1 (20C69) running on a late 2015 iMac.